# Синтаксическая ошибка

Tags: php

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
> T_STRING in
> /home/hyeworld/hyeworld.com/html/port.php
> on line 3 <? php
>
> session_start ();
>
> mysql_connect
> ("localhost","hyeworld",.......

Comment: Вообще функция mysql_connect возвращает идентификатор соединения. Поэтому нужно присваивать переменной, которую Вы потом будите использовать в запросах

Comment: Вы бы 3-ю строчку полностью скопипастили сюда. А то ошибка именно в ней, а вы ее обрезали

Answer (score 1):

Создайте файл `conf.php`. В нем присвой значение переменным

```
<?php
  $host='localhost;
  $login='hyeworld';
  $parol='пароль';
  $dbname='имя БД';
?>
```

Далее, в своем файле, в которым вы это пишите, делайте так:

```
<?php
  require_once ("conf.php");
  session_start();
  mysql_connect ($host, $login, $parol);
  mysql_select_db($dbname);
  .................
?>
```

Вот вроде так...

Comment: Ну это даже не совет...<br>
Это просто Вы предлагаете отделить конфиг

Comment: А тебя что именно не устраиват? Сделай в одном тоже самое. Какая разница то?

Answer (score -1):

У вас ошибка в первой строке:

```
<? php
```

Из-за пробела интерпретатор раcпознает первую строку как открывающий тег и  php как отдельный элемент с незакрытой строкой, и поэтому ругается на строку 3.

Либо сделайте

```
<?php
```

Либо

```
<?
```

Comment: short_open_tags уже выпилен из PHP. <? - не вариант. А вот по поводу пробела - вы правы.

Comment: это зависит от используемо версии. Сильно сомневаюсь что автор использует свежую версию php.

Comment: Независимо от версии, использзовать короткие тэги сегодня - дурной тон.

Comment: Только заметил что вопрос задан 5 лет назад

Comment: @ilyaplot, в контексте вопроса, речь идет о том, что интерпретатор их распознает и в сумме с пробелом перед php получается такая картина. А в вопрос их использования я с вами полностью согласен